# Powershell string in pattern

Tags: arrays, string, powershell, pattern-matching

i writing small script in Powershell and i have no idea for another steps...

I have array with:

```
$666 = "abrakadabra","blabla/blabla","blabla/abraka_dabra(20_10_2015).bla"
```

In file saved on HDD, i have file, named as content.txt. In this file i need find string from array. With "abrakadabra" and "blabla/blabla" i dont have problems, but with "blabla/abraka_dabra(20_10_2015).bla" yes.

As part of script i triing this with:

```
foreach ( $line in $666 ) { select-string content.txt -pattern $line }
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: `Select-String -Path content.txt -Pattern $666 -SimpleMatch`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to escape the special chars from your patterns, here is an easy way:

`$666 |% {select-string content.txt -pattern ([RegEx]::Escape($_))  }`